# How would you model a pyramid pattern?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I’m trying to model this kettle with a pyramid pattern on the lower side of the kettle. The problem that I am facing is that I have a Subdivision Surface modifier on the object to give it that smooth round look. If I try to model each individual pyramid, the Subsurf smooths out the pyramid.

What is the best way of achieving this look?

[image: kettle model]

[image: kettle photograph]

Answer (score 26):

You can model the pyramids either scaling extruded individual faces to 0 and then removing doubles(<kbd>w</kbd>-><kbd>r</kbd>), or you could poke the faces(<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) and then select the middle vertices by the amount of adjacent faces or connecting edges(<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> menu) and use Shrink/Flatten(<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) to move them outwards in the direction the surface is facing. You could then grow selection(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) and bevel(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>) the edges so they remain sharp(ish) after Subdivision Surface modifier. You could crease the edges(<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>) instead of beveling to have them completely sharp with the Subsurf, but that would be a bit unrealistic since edges are rarely completely sharp.
[image: Pyramid Pattern]

Answer (score 0):

Edit mode:
Enable face select

Select a ring of faces by having cursor in between adjacent face

[image]

Separate by selection
[image]

Poke

Object mode:
Select new object

Edit mode:

Select all
[image]

< I > inset
Select individual in tool properties

[image]

Scale
Drag outward
[image]

Object mode:

Parent new object to original

Adjust settings / remove subsurf modifier on child object
[image]

Comment: This answer does not seem to address the issue with Subdivision Surface modifier described  in the question.

Comment: It **does** as separated pyramids are not gonna be smoothed with the rest. And that's what the guy wants. Can't you put two and two together? Now, kindly upvote me please.

Comment: You will have a surface full of holes then. The differences between subdivided and lower detail parts tend to be visible. That does not seem like a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct method is to just use [poke faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#poke-faces).

If they are not extruding much and you don't need a close-up shot, it might be a better idea to do it with a normal map.

Answer (score -1):

Use Smooth Vertex tool on selected vertices. Or separate, by selection, pyramids, that are poked faces made with <kbd>Alt+P</kbd> ,and give the rest Smooth shading (Tools).

Answer (score -1):

You might consider separating the geometry into two meshes.

One mesh keeps the subdivision surface (although you might have to crease it near the edges that got separated).

The other mesh *applies* the subdivision surface modifier, and then you use the Poke Faces tactic suggested by the other posters.

Alternately, increase the Crease factor of the edges of the pyramids so that the subdivision surface does not curve them at all.